# Viterbi algorithm in java

Tags: java, nlp, hidden-markov-models, viterbi

I'm doing the coursera NLP course and the first programming assignment is to build a Viterbi decoder. I think I'm really close to finishing it but there is some elusive bug which I cannot seem to be able to trace. Here is my code:

http://pastie.org/private/ksmbns3gjctedu1zxrehw

http://pastie.org/private/ssv6tc8dwnamn2qegdvww

So far I've debugged the "teaching" related functions so I can say that the parameters for the algorithms are being correctly estimated. Of particular interest is the viterbi() and findW() methods. The definition of the algorithm I'm using can be found here: http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~mcollins/hmms-spring2013.pdf on page 18.

One thing which I'm having hard time wrapping my head around is how am I supposed to update the backpointers for the special cases when K = {1, 2} (in my case this is 0 and 1, since I'm zero-indexing my array) respectively the parameters I'm using in those cases are q({TAGSET} | *, *) and q ({TAGSET} | *, {TAGSET}).

Hints rather than spoon-fed answers will also be highly appreciated!

Comment: Your code is much too long (and therefore localized) to make a good SO question, especially since you don't describe what your actual bug is (are you getting an error? Unexpected behavior?)

Comment: I've already solved the problem and the code can be found here: https://github.com/lorddoskias/NLP/tree/master/src/hmmtagger in case someone else is interested.

Comment: +1 For posting the code. Wondering if you mind explaining what was the issue and how you fixed it.

Comment: it wasn't anything major. I had some errors with calculating the backpointer indices (I had transposed the two parameters). And also I simplified a bit the inner viterbi loop in findW. For more info check my github repo: https://github.com/lorddoskias/NLP

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple implementation of viterbi decoder by Yusuke Shunyama =) http://cs.nyu.edu/yusuke/course/NLP/viterbi/Viterbi.java

```
/*
 * Viterbi.java
 * Toy Viterbi Decorder
 *
 * by Yusuke Shinyama <yusuke at cs . nyu . edu>
 *
 *   Permission to use, copy, modify, distribute this software 
 *   for any purpose is hereby granted without fee, provided 
 *   that the above copyright notice appear in all copies and
 *   that both that copyright notice and this permission notice
 *   appear in supporting documentation.
 */

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;


class Symbol {
    public String name;

    public Symbol(String s) {
    name = s;
    }
}

class SymbolTable {
    Hashtable table;

    public SymbolTable() {
    table = new Hashtable();
    }
    public Symbol intern(String s) {
    s = s.toLowerCase();
    Object sym = table.get(s);
    if (sym == null) {
        sym = new Symbol(s);
        table.put(s, sym);
    }
    return (Symbol)sym;
    }
}

class SymbolList {
    Vector list;

    public SymbolList() {
    list = new Vector();
    }
    public int size() {
    return list.size();
    }
    public void set(int index, Symbol sym) {
    list.setElementAt(sym, index);
    }
    public void add(Symbol sym) {
    list.addElement(sym);
    }
    public Symbol get(int index) {
    return (Symbol) list.elementAt(index);
    }
}

class IntegerList {
    Vector list;

    public IntegerList() {
    list = new Vector();
    }
    public int size() {
    return list.size();
    }
    public void set(int index, int i) {
    list.setElementAt(new Integer(i), index);
    }
    public void add(int i) {
    list.addElement(new Integer(i));
    }
    public int get(int index) {
    return ((Integer)list.elementAt(index)).intValue();
    }
}

class ProbTable {
    Hashtable table;

    public ProbTable() {
    table = new Hashtable();
    }
    public void put(Object obj, double prob) {
    table.put(obj, new Double(prob));
    }
    public double get(Object obj) {
    Double prob = (Double)table.get(obj);
    if (prob == null) {
        return 0.0;
    }
    return prob.doubleValue();
    }
    // normalize probability
    public void normalize() {
    double total = 0.0;
    for(Enumeration e = table.elements() ; e.hasMoreElements() ;) {
        total += ((Double)e.nextElement()).doubleValue();
    }
    if (total == 0.0) {
        return;     // div by zero!
    }
    for(Enumeration e = table.keys() ; e.hasMoreElements() ;) {
        Object k = e.nextElement();
        double prob = ((Double)table.get(k)).doubleValue();
        table.put(k, new Double(prob / total));
    }
    }
}

class State {
    public String name;
    ProbTable emits;
    ProbTable linksto;

    public State(String s) {
    name = s;
    emits = new ProbTable();
    linksto = new ProbTable();
    }

    public void normalize() {
    emits.normalize();
    linksto.normalize();
    }

    public void addSymbol(Symbol sym, double prob) {
    emits.put(sym, prob);
    }

    public double emitprob(Symbol sym) {
    return emits.get(sym);
    }

    public void addLink(State st, double prob) {
    linksto.put(st, prob);
    }

    public double transprob(State st) {
    return linksto.get(st);
    }
}

class StateTable {
    Hashtable table;

    public StateTable() {
    table = new Hashtable();
    }
    public State get(String s) {
    s = s.toUpperCase();
    State st = (State)table.get(s);
    if (st == null) {
        st = new State(s);
        table.put(s, st);
    }
    return st;
    }
}

class StateIDTable {
    Hashtable table;

    public StateIDTable() {
    table = new Hashtable();
    }
    public void put(State obj, int i) {
    table.put(obj, new Integer(i));
    }
    public int get(State obj) {
    Integer i = (Integer)table.get(obj);
    if (i == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return i.intValue();
    }
}

class StateList {
    Vector list;

    public StateList() {
    list = new Vector();
    }
    public int size() {
    return list.size();
    }
    public void set(int index, State st) {
    list.setElementAt(st, index);
    }
    public void add(State st) {
    list.addElement(st);
    }
    public State get(int index) {
    return (State) list.elementAt(index);
    }
}

class HMMCanvas extends Canvas {
    static final int grid_x = 60;
    static final int grid_y = 40;
    static final int offset_x = 70;
    static final int offset_y = 30;
    static final int offset_y2 = 10;
    static final int offset_y3 = 65;
    static final int col_x = 40;
    static final int col_y = 10;
    static final int state_r = 10;
    static final Color state_fill = Color.white;
    static final Color state_fill_maximum = Color.yellow;
    static final Color state_fill_best = Color.red;
    static final Color state_boundery = Color.black;
    static final Color link_normal = Color.green;
    static final Color link_processed = Color.blue;
    static final Color link_maximum = Color.red;

    HMMDecoder hmm;

    public HMMCanvas() {
    setBackground(Color.white);
    setSize(400,300);
    }

    public void setHMM(HMMDecoder h) {
    hmm = h;
    }

    private void drawState(Graphics g, int x, int y, Color c) {
    x = x * grid_x + offset_x;
    y = y * grid_y + offset_y;
    g.setColor(c);
    g.fillOval(x-state_r, y-state_r, state_r*2, state_r*2);
    g.setColor(state_boundery);
    g.drawOval(x-state_r, y-state_r, state_r*2, state_r*2);
    }

    private void drawLink(Graphics g, int x, int y0, int y1, Color c) {
    int x0 = grid_x * x + offset_x;
    int x1 = grid_x * (x+1) + offset_x;
    y0 = y0 * grid_y + offset_y;
    y1 = y1 * grid_y + offset_y;
    g.setColor(c);
    g.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);
    }

    private void drawCenterString(Graphics g, String s, int x, int y) {
    x = x - g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(s)/2;
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawString(s, x, y+5);
    }

    private void drawRightString(Graphics g, String s, int x, int y) {
    x = x - g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(s);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawString(s, x, y+5);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    if (hmm == null) {
        return;
    }
    DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("0.0000");
    int nsymbols = hmm.symbols.size();
    int nstates = hmm.states.size();
    // complete graph.
    for(int i = 0; i < nsymbols; i++) {
        int offset_ymax = offset_y2+nstates*grid_y;
        if (i < nsymbols-1) {
        for(int y1 = 0; y1 < nstates; y1++) {
            for(int y0 = 0; y0 < nstates; y0++) {
            Color c = link_normal;
            if (hmm.stage == i+1 && hmm.i0 == y0 && hmm.i1 == y1) {
                c = link_processed;
            }
            if (hmm.matrix_prevstate[i+1][y1] == y0) {
                c = link_maximum;
            }
            drawLink(g, i, y0, y1, c);
            if (c == link_maximum && 0 < i) {
                double transprob = hmm.states.get(y0).transprob(hmm.states.get(y1));
                drawCenterString(g, form.format(transprob),
                         offset_x + i*grid_x + grid_x/2, offset_ymax);
                offset_ymax = offset_ymax + 16;
            }
            }
        }
        }
        // state circles.
        for(int y = 0; y < nstates; y++) {
        Color c = state_fill;
        if (hmm.matrix_prevstate[i][y] != -1) {
            c = state_fill_maximum;
        }
        if (hmm.sequence.size() == nsymbols && 
            hmm.sequence.get(nsymbols-1-i) == y) {
            c = state_fill_best;
        }
        drawState(g, i, y, c);
        }
    }
    // max probability.
    for(int i = 0; i < nsymbols; i++) {
        for(int y1 = 0; y1 < nstates; y1++) {
        if (hmm.matrix_prevstate[i][y1] != -1) {
            drawCenterString(g, form.format(hmm.matrix_maxprob[i][y1]),
                     offset_x+i*grid_x, offset_y+y1*grid_y);
        }
        }
    }

    // captions (symbols atop)
    for(int i = 0; i < nsymbols; i++) {
        drawCenterString(g, hmm.symbols.get(i).name, offset_x+i*grid_x, col_y);
    }
    // captions (states in left)
    for(int y = 0; y < nstates; y++) {
        drawRightString(g, hmm.states.get(y).name, col_x, offset_y+y*grid_y);
    }

    // status bar
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawString(hmm.status, col_x, offset_y3+nstates*grid_y);
    g.drawString(hmm.status2, col_x, offset_y3+nstates*grid_y+16);
    }
}

class HMMDecoder {
    StateList states;
    int state_start;
    int state_end;

    public IntegerList sequence;
    public double[][] matrix_maxprob;
    public int[][] matrix_prevstate;
    public SymbolList symbols;
    public double probmax;
    public int stage, i0, i1;
    public boolean laststage;
    public String status, status2;

    public HMMDecoder() {
    status = "Not initialized.";
    status2 = "";
    states = new StateList();
    }

    public void addStartState(State st) {
    state_start = states.size(); // get current index
    states.add(st);
    }
    public void addNormalState(State st) {
    states.add(st);
    }
    public void addEndState(State st) {
    state_end = states.size(); // get current index
    states.add(st);
    }

    // for debugging.
    public void showmatrix() {
    for(int i = 0; i < symbols.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < states.size(); j++) {
        System.out.print(matrix_maxprob[i][j]+" "+matrix_prevstate[i][j]+", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    }

    // initialize for decoding
    public void initialize(SymbolList syms) {
    // symbols[syms.length] should be END
    symbols = syms;
    matrix_maxprob = new double[symbols.size()][states.size()];
    matrix_prevstate = new int[symbols.size()][states.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < symbols.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < states.size(); j++) {
        matrix_prevstate[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }

    State start = states.get(state_start);
    for(int i = 0; i < states.size(); i++) {
        matrix_maxprob[0][i] = start.transprob(states.get(i));
        matrix_prevstate[0][i] = 0;
    }

    stage = 0;
    i0 = -1;
    i1 = -1;
    sequence = new IntegerList();
    status = "Ok, let's get started...";
    status2 = "";
    }

    // forward procedure
    public boolean proceed_decoding() {
    status2 = "";
    // already end?
    if (symbols.size() <= stage) {
        return false;
    }
    // not started?
    if (stage == 0) {
        stage = 1;
        i0 = 0;
        i1 = 0;
        matrix_maxprob[stage][i1] = 0.0;
    } else {
        i0++;
        if (states.size() <= i0) {
        // i0 should be reinitialized.
        i0 = 0;
        i1++;
        if (states.size() <= i1) {
            // i1 should be reinitialized.
            // goto next stage.
            stage++;
            if (symbols.size() <= stage) {
            // done.
            status = "Decoding finished.";
            return false;
            }
            laststage = (stage == symbols.size()-1);
            i1 = 0;
        }
        matrix_maxprob[stage][i1] = 0.0;
        }
    }

    // sym1: next symbol
    Symbol sym1 = symbols.get(stage);
    State s0 = states.get(i0);
    State s1 = states.get(i1);

    // precond: 1 <= stage.
    double prob = matrix_maxprob[stage-1][i0];
    DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("0.0000");
    status = "Prob:" + form.format(prob);

    if (1 < stage) {
        // skip first stage.
        double transprob = s0.transprob(s1);
        prob = prob * transprob;
        status = status + " x " + form.format(transprob);
    }

    double emitprob = s1.emitprob(sym1);
    prob = prob * emitprob;
    status = status + " x " + form.format(emitprob) + "(" + s1.name+":"+sym1.name + ")";

    status = status + " = " + form.format(prob);
    // System.out.println("stage: "+stage+", i0:"+i0+", i1:"+i1+", prob:"+prob);

    if (matrix_maxprob[stage][i1] < prob) {
        matrix_maxprob[stage][i1] = prob;
        matrix_prevstate[stage][i1] = i0;
        status2 = "(new maximum found)";
    }

    return true;
    }

    // backward proc
    public void backward() {
    int probmaxstate = state_end;
    sequence.add(probmaxstate);
    for(int i = symbols.size()-1; 0 < i; i--) {
        probmaxstate = matrix_prevstate[i][probmaxstate];
        if (probmaxstate == -1) {
        status2 = "Decoding failed.";
        return;
        }
        sequence.add(probmaxstate);
        //System.out.println("stage: "+i+", state:"+probmaxstate);
    }
    }
}


public class Viterbi extends Applet implements ActionListener, Runnable {
    SymbolTable symtab;
    StateTable sttab;
    HMMDecoder myhmm = null;
    HMMCanvas canvas;
    Panel p;
    TextArea hmmdesc;
    TextField sentence;
    Button bstart, bskip;
    static final String initialHMM =
    "start: go(cow,1.0)\n" + 
    "cow: emit(moo,0.9) emit(hello,0.1) go(cow,0.5) go(duck,0.3) go(end,0.2)\n" +
    "duck: emit(quack,0.6) emit(hello,0.4) go(duck,0.5) go(cow,0.3) go(end,0.2)\n";

    final int sleepmillisec = 100; // 0.1s

    // setup hmm
    // success:true.
    boolean setupHMM(String s) {
    myhmm = new HMMDecoder();
    symtab = new SymbolTable();
    sttab = new StateTable();

    State start = sttab.get("start");
    State end = sttab.get("end");
    myhmm.addStartState(start);

    boolean success = true;
    StringTokenizer lines = new StringTokenizer(s, "\n");
    while (lines.hasMoreTokens()) {
        // foreach line.
        String line = lines.nextToken();
        int i = line.indexOf(':');
        if (i == -1) break;
        State st0 = sttab.get(line.substring(0,i).trim());
        if (st0 != start && st0 != end) {
        myhmm.addNormalState(st0);
        }
        //System.out.println(st0.name+":"+line.substring(i+1));

        StringTokenizer tokenz = new StringTokenizer(line.substring(i+1), ", ");
        while (tokenz.hasMoreTokens()) {
        // foreach token.
        String t = tokenz.nextToken().toLowerCase();
        if (t.startsWith("go(")) {
            State st1 = sttab.get(t.substring(3).trim());
            // fetch another token.
            if (!tokenz.hasMoreTokens()) {
            success = false; // err. nomoretoken
            break;
            }
            String n = tokenz.nextToken().replace(')', ' ');
            double prob;
            try {
            prob = Double.valueOf(n).doubleValue();
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            success = false; // err.
            prob = 0.0;
            }
            st0.addLink(st1, prob);
            //System.out.println("go:"+st1.name+","+prob);
        } else if (t.startsWith("emit(")) {
            Symbol sym = symtab.intern(t.substring(5).trim());
            // fetch another token.
            if (!tokenz.hasMoreTokens()) {
            success = false; // err. nomoretoken
            break;
            }
            String n = tokenz.nextToken().replace(')', ' ');
            double prob;
            try {
            prob = Double.valueOf(n).doubleValue();
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            success = false; // err.
            prob = 0.0;
            }
            st0.addSymbol(sym, prob);
            //System.out.println("emit:"+sym.name+","+prob);
        } else {
            // illegal syntax, just ignore
            break;
        }
        }

        st0.normalize();    // normalize probability
    }

    end.addSymbol(symtab.intern("end"), 1.0);
    myhmm.addEndState(end);

    return success;
    }

    // success:true.
    boolean setup() {
    if (! setupHMM(hmmdesc.getText()))
        return false;

    // initialize words
    SymbolList words = new SymbolList();
    StringTokenizer tokenz = new StringTokenizer(sentence.getText());
    words.add(symtab.intern("start"));
    while (tokenz.hasMoreTokens()) {
        words.add(symtab.intern(tokenz.nextToken()));
    }
    words.add(symtab.intern("end"));
    myhmm.initialize(words);
    canvas.setHMM(myhmm);
    return true;
    }

    public void init() {
    canvas = new HMMCanvas();

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p = new Panel();
    sentence = new TextField("moo hello quack", 20);
    bstart = new Button("  Start  ");
    bskip = new Button("Auto");
    bstart.addActionListener(this);
    bskip.addActionListener(this);
    p.add(sentence);
    p.add(bstart);
    p.add(bskip);
    hmmdesc = new TextArea(initialHMM, 4, 20);
    add("North", canvas);
    add("Center", p);
    add("South", hmmdesc);

    }

    void setup_fallback() {
    // adjustable
    State cow = sttab.get("cow");
    State duck = sttab.get("duck");
    State end = sttab.get("end");

    cow.addLink  (cow,  0.5);
    cow.addLink  (duck, 0.3);
    cow.addLink  (end,  0.2);
    duck.addLink (cow,  0.3);
    duck.addLink (duck, 0.5);
    duck.addLink (end,  0.2);   

    cow.addSymbol(symtab.intern("moo"), 0.9);
    cow.addSymbol(symtab.intern("hello"), 0.1);
    duck.addSymbol(symtab.intern("quack"), 0.6);
    duck.addSymbol(symtab.intern("hello"), 0.4);
    }

    public void destroy() {
        remove(p);
        remove(canvas);
    }

    public void processEvent(AWTEvent e) {
        if (e.getID() == Event.WINDOW_DESTROY) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public void run() {
    if (myhmm != null) {
        while (myhmm.proceed_decoding()) {
        canvas.repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleepmillisec);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            ;
        }
        }
        myhmm.backward();
        canvas.repaint();
        bstart.setLabel("  Start  ");
        bstart.setEnabled(true);
        bskip.setEnabled(true);
        myhmm = null;
    }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
    String label = ev.getActionCommand();

    if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("  start  ")) {
        if (!setup()) {
        // error
        return;
        }
        bstart.setLabel("Proceed");
        canvas.repaint();
    } else if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("proceed")) {
        // next
        if (! myhmm.proceed_decoding()) {
        myhmm.backward();
        bstart.setLabel("  Start  ");
        myhmm = null;
        }
        canvas.repaint();
    } else if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("auto")) {
        // skip
        if (myhmm == null) {
        if (!setup()) {
            // error
            return;
        }
        }
        bstart.setEnabled(false);
        bskip.setEnabled(false);
        Thread me = new Thread(this);
        me.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        // start animation.
        me.start();
    }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    Frame f = new Frame("Viterbi");
    Viterbi v = new Viterbi();
    f.add("Center", v);
    f.setSize(400, 400);
    f.show();
    v.init();
    v.start();
    }

    public String getAppletInfo() {
        return "A Sample Viterbi Decoder Applet";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some suggestions:

1. You should draw out the HMM lattice if you have any confusion about how transitions are occurring in your model.
   For instance, you can view transitions to the first hidden state as originating from a single start hidden state, so the backpointer for k=0 would always have to point to this start state. In your code, you probably should not be looping over hidden states for k=0 in `findW` (which seems correct), but you probably should be looping for k=1.
2. Usually multiplying transition and emission probabilities in HMM inference lead to very small floating point values, which can lead to numerical errors. You should add log probabilities instead of multiplying probabilities.
3. To check viterbi or forward-backward implementations, I usually also write a brute force method and compare the output of each. If the brute-force and dynamic-programming algorithm match on short sequences, then that gives a reasonable measure of confidence that both are correct.